# Disable all anchor tags on asp.net page using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, anchor

I have multiple anchor tags on my web page and I am currently using the following method to disable a hyperlink

Here is code

```
<a href="mylink" id="CA" runat="server">Curretn Activity</a>
CA.Attributes["Onclick"] = "";
```

There are multiple links like above and I want to enable and disable on different conditions. But I want to do this using loop method that when a specific condition becomes true then all hyperlinks should be enabled or disabled on page. Can anyone tell me how can I do this in c#?

Comment: What technology are you using? Meaning ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, something else? Or you're just trying to modify static web page via WinForms app? Or?..

Comment: @user1103342: Please spellcheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can use jquery then code below is to register a client script from code behind to disable all anchor links in a page:

```
protected void Page_Load(..)
{
    String strScript = "$('a').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });";

    if(condition)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "disableAnchor", strScript, true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"return false" in the onclick eventhandler
or href="javascript:void(0)"

Not too sure about the first solution, but the second will definitely work.